# Typescript property augmentation with augmented type

Tags: typescript, types

I have augmented an interface from a library which is used by another interface of the library.

Library ('@liskhq/lisk-transactions' npm package) declarations :

```js
export interface StateStoreCache<T> {
    cache(filterArray: ReadonlyArray<{
        readonly [key: string]: string;
    }>): Promise<ReadonlyArray<T>>;
}
export interface StateStorePrepare {
    readonly account: StateStoreCache<Account>;
    readonly transaction: StateStoreCache<TransactionJSON>;
}
```

Augmentation attempt #1

```js
import '@liskhq/lisk-transactions';
import {AccountFilter} from "./filters.account";
import {TransactionFilter} from "./filters.transaction";

declare module '@liskhq/lisk-transactions' {

    interface Account {
        asset: object;
    }

    interface StateStoreCache<T> {
        cache(filterArray: ReadonlyArray<AccountFilter | TransactionFilter>): Promise<ReadonlyArray<T>>;
    }
}
```

With this augmentation, the `StateStoreCache` type is not actually augmented, which is weird because the `Account` interface is.
If to this augmentation I add the `StateStorePrepare` type :

Augmentation attempt #2

```js
import '@liskhq/lisk-transactions';
import {TransactionJSON} from "@liskhq/lisk-transactions/dist-node/transaction_types";
import {AccountFilter} from "./filters.account";
import {TransactionFilter} from "./filters.transaction";

declare module '@liskhq/lisk-transactions' {

    interface Account {
        asset: object;
    }

    interface StateStoreCache<T> {
        cache(filterArray: ReadonlyArray<AccountFilter | TransactionFilter>): Promise<ReadonlyArray<T>>;
    }

    interface StateStorePrepare {
        readonly account: StateStoreCache<Account>; // ERROR
        readonly transaction: StateStoreCache<TransactionJSON>; // ERROR
    }
}
```

In this case I get a compiler error : `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'account' must be of type 'StateStoreCache<Account>', but here has type 'StateStoreCache<Account>'.` which I understand, you can't change properties definition.

How am I supposed to do to get my type augmentation ?

Comment: This is working as intended - lib types cannot be changed, only augmented. You can use a wrapper module for `'@liskhq/lisk-transactions'` which matches your domain types.

Comment: I've never read anything about wrapper modules ; can you elaborate or link me an example ? Also if you make and "answer" I can mark it as correct answer if it ends up solving my issue

Comment: By [wrapper module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) I just meant a layer of abstraction around your library to offer a cleaner interfaces/types to your domain logic. This approach is much more flexible than trying to augment types, which is rather used for type hotfixes.